# CMake command line in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I need to compile a basic linear algebra library (https://www.openblas.net/) using Microsoft Visual C (MSVC). The web site includes a dll created with mingw, but I need to make sure that all dlls are created by the same compiler.
I downloaded the source files (>2000 C programs, no C++) and used the built-in CMake support in VS (right-click the folder containing CMakeLists.txt and select **build**). That worked very well.
Now I need a command-line version of the same thing, so I can include it in the Travis CI workflow of our project. To do that, I ran

```
vcvars64.bat
cmake -S "C:\BLAS\OpenBLAS-v0.3.10\OpenBLAS-0.3.10" -B "C:\BLAS\OpenBLAS-v0.3.10\OpenBLAS-0.3.10\out"
```

This didn't create any new versions of the .obj files, so it looks like I am overlooking something that I didn't find when I ran cmake -h.
Here is the output:

```
C:\BLAS\OpenBLAS-v0.3.10\OpenBLAS-0.3.10\out>cmake -S "C:\BLAS\OpenBLAS-v0.3.10\OpenBLAS-0.3.10" -B "C:\BLAS\OpenBLAS-v0.3.10\OpenBLAS-0.3.10\out"
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:66 (message):
  CMake support is experimental.  It does not yet support all build options
  and may not produce the same Makefiles that OpenBLAS ships with.


-- GEMM multithread threshold set to 4.
-- Multi-threading enabled with 4 threads.
CMake Deprecation Warning at C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/CMakeForceCompiler.cmake:103 (message):
  The CMAKE_FORCE_Fortran_COMPILER macro is deprecated.  Instead just set
  CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER and allow CMake to identify the compiler.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/f_check.cmake:27 (CMAKE_FORCE_Fortran_COMPILER)
  cmake/prebuild.cmake:89 (include)
  cmake/system.cmake:157 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:69 (include)


CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/prebuild.cmake:472 (if):
  Policy CMP0054 is not set: Only interpret if() arguments as variables or
  keywords when unquoted.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0054" for policy
  details.  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this
  warning.

  Quoted variables like "MSVC" will no longer be dereferenced when the policy
  is set to NEW.  Since the policy is not set the OLD behavior will be used.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/system.cmake:157 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:69 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

MSVC
-- Running getarch
-- GETARCH results:
CORE=generic
LIBCORE=generic
NUM_CORES=4
GENERIC=1
L1_DATA_SIZE=32768
L1_DATA_LINESIZE=128
L2_SIZE=512488
L2_LINESIZE=128
DTB_DEFAULT_ENTRIES=128
DTB_SIZE=4096
L2_ASSOCIATIVE=8
MAKE += -j 4

-- Compiling a 64-bit binary.
-- Building Single Precision
-- Building Double Precision
-- Building Complex Precision
-- Building Double Complex Precision
-- Reading vars from C:/BLAS/OpenBLAS-v0.3.10/OpenBLAS-0.3.10/kernel/x86_64/KERNEL...
-- Reading vars from C:/BLAS/OpenBLAS-v0.3.10/OpenBLAS-0.3.10/kernel/x86_64/KERNEL.generic...
CMake Warning (dev) at utest/CMakeLists.txt:4 (if):
  Policy CMP0054 is not set: Only interpret if() arguments as variables or
  keywords when unquoted.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0054" for policy
  details.  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this
  warning.

  Quoted variables like "MSVC" will no longer be dereferenced when the policy
  is set to NEW.  Since the policy is not set the OLD behavior will be used.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Generating openblas_config.h in include/openblas
-- Generating f77blas.h in include/openblas
-- Generating cblas.h in include/openblas
-- Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/BLAS/OpenBLAS-v0.3.10/OpenBLAS-0.3.10/out

C:\BLAS\OpenBLAS-v0.3.10\OpenBLAS-0.3.10\out>
```

Comment: CMake doesn't **compile** anything - it is a buildsystem generator. So, you wouldn't expect any .obj files to be created by invoking `cmake`. After generating the buildsystem using CMake, you need to invoke the compiler to actually build your project. This can be done, for example, by running `make`, or running the Visual Studio compiler in your case. CMake offers a command line shortcut to **build** the generated buildsystem with `cmake --build .` See the response to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42881758/3987854) for typical CMake command line usage.

Comment: Yes! Thanks! Together, `vcvars64.bat`, `cmake`, and `cmake --build` compile everything and create a `.lib`. Should `cmake` also create the `dll`, or should I use `link.exe` for that?

Comment: I'm assuming you're following [these](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/wiki/How-to-use-OpenBLAS-in-Microsoft-Visual-Studio#1-native-msvc-abi) instructions, which say "*If you would rather have a DLL, add `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON` above...*" so add `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON` to your first `cmake` command. FWIW, the MinGW [instructions](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/wiki/How-to-use-OpenBLAS-in-Microsoft-Visual-Studio#2-gnu-mingw-abi) further down the page are not well tested, and considered "experimental"...

Comment: Thanks! That works, eliminating the need for me to write a link statement. My commands are now:
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"`

`cmake -G "Ninja" -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="C:\BLAS\OpenBLAS-v0.3.10\OpenBLAS-0.3.10\out\install\x64-Release" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=cl -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=ninja "C:\BLAS\OpenBLAS-v0.3.10\OpenBLAS-0.3.10" >cmakeOut.txt`

`cmake --build "C:\BLAS\OpenBLAS-v0.3.10\OpenBLAS-0.3.10" <cmakeBuildOut.txt`